# jQuery Program Requirements

Tags: jquery

How to run jQuery program ? at what kind of things i have to install?

Comment: Are u new to Computer Programing??

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is not a program and you don't run it. It's a JavaScript library that helps you with cross-browser development. You just include it in your page and then use it in your JavaScript code. See [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) for some tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to include jQuery to your html:

```
<!-- jQquery -->
<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now you can use all jQuery possibilities in your html.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is for websites to use, it doesn't run locally on your computer as a standalone thing...all you need is a modern web browser (something in the past 8 years-ish) and go browsing.

Sites, like the one you're on now, use it to save on JavaScript code and abstract some cross-browser inconsistencies...but unless you're *writing* a website (which is a different question), you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

[jquery](http://jquery.com/) is not a program. jquery is a framework based on javascript. So basically a browser could be used to render an HTML page containing jquery code. Of course this HTML page needs to be hosted somewhere like for example a web server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery the only thing you have to do is download/save this file   http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js

Then include it in your html file and your ready to go.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```